# Empty object on delete req.body in Express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I'm trying to delete something on the server side (Express.js). Hence, I need to send a data from frontend (React with Redux) to be used on the backend in order to delete something from a db. So my redux action looks like that:

```
export const sendRemoved = (removedDocId) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.delete('/api/deletedoc', removedDocId);
}
```

As you can see I want to send object called removedDocId (which has some precious data). Then on the backend side I'm doing this:

```
app.delete('/api/deletedoc', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

I'm expecting to have my data inside the req.body but instead I'm getting empty object. If I would do the same with a post method (both on frontend and backend) all would work. Is there another way for passing data from frontend to backend using delete method?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of just using the `removedDocId` string as the second argument, you could use it in the `data` property of the options object instead.

```
export const sendRemoved = (removedDocId) => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.delete('/api/deletedoc', { data: { removedDocId } });
}
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks. I was using just {  removeDocId }